# How to change ng-model value ?

Tags: angularjs

I have check boxes

```
<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="checked" >

<input  type='text' ng-disabled="checked" >
```

This disables a textbox when is  checked, but how do i do that from a function  ? like:

```
function change(){
$scope.checked = true;
}
```

i need it because i have

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function(event) {
            change();
        });
```

This changes the value but that doesn't disable the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event (click) comes from outside of the angular world. So you have to wrap the code in an `$apply` block:

```
function change(){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
       $scope.checked = true;
    });
}
```

The `change` function is correct.

Comment: thx, i found some examples of $apply but now i understand how why to use it.